# Integral - different from $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to find $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)cos(x)}dx$. This function is always $>0$ so its integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ should be different from $0$. But when i found the indefinite integral, I got $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan(\frac{2\tan + 1}{\sqrt{3}})$, which gives the same result for $x=2\pi$ and for $x=0$, so my integral is equal to $0$. Can somebody help me find a mistake in my way of thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, the primitive must be a differentiable function on $[0,2\pi]$. But it's not even defined at $\pi/2$.

Comment: Ok, I get it. But my argument why this integral is $>0$ is ok, right?

Comment: @Anne Yes, this reasoning is sound!

Answer (score 1):

We have the integrand as
$$\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{\sin(2x)}2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \dfrac{\sin^k(2x)}{2^k}$$ Now use the technique mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367709/finding-the-complex-trig-integral-using-the-method-of-residues-for-int-pi/367714#367714) to get what you want.

Comment: Ok. But what's wrong with what I wrote? There must be a mistake, but I don't see it. And it is true that this integral is $>0$, right?

Answer (score 0):

This integral can be done using complex variables. Put $z=e^{ix}$ to get
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{1+\sin(x)\cos(x)} dx =
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{iz} \frac{1}{1+1/(4i)(z-1/z)(z+1/z)} dz \\=
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{iz} \frac{4iz^2}{4iz^2+(z^2-1)(z^2+1)} dz =
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{4z}{4iz^2+(z^2-1)(z^2+1)} dz.$$
Using e.g. the quadratic formula we see that the four poles of the integrand are given by
$$z_{0,1,2,3} =\pm \sqrt{\pm i\sqrt{3}-2i}.$$
Of these, only $z_{0,1}$ are inside the unit circle:
$$z_{0,1} = \pm \sqrt{i\sqrt{3}-2i}.$$
The residues $w_{0,1}$ at these poles are given by
$$w_{0,1} = \lim_{z\to z_{0,1}} \frac{4z}{8iz+4z^3} 
=\lim_{z\to z_{0,1}} \frac{1}{2i+z^2} =
\frac{1}{2i+i\sqrt{3}-2i} = -i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}.$$
It follows that the value of the integral is
$$2\pi i \times 2 \times -i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} = \frac{4\pi\sqrt{3}}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

@Anne : your integrand is positive so your answer must be positive.  If you use $\sin(x)\cos(x)=\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$, use the substitution $y = 2x$, and use the $2\pi$-periodicity of $\sin$, eventually you get something like $2\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{2+\sin(y)}\,dy$.  By the symmetry of $\sin$, this can be further simplified to  $4\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{2+\sin(y)}\,dy$.  You can find the antiderivative using the "Weierstrass substitution" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution, and it has probably been discussed here *ad nauseum*)  but based on your question, it appears that maybe you already know how to do it.  Maple gives me 
$\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{3}\tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(2\tan(\frac{y}{2})+1))$ for the antiderivative. This is well-defined when $y = \pm \frac{\pi}{2}$.

The indefinite integral you originally got is clearly wrong because it is periodic, which is impossible because your integrand is always positive. This is the case even if there is a way to deal with the singularities where $\tan(x)$ is undefined.  I don't know exactly what went wrong without seeing how you got it, but remember that $\tan(\theta) = s$ does not always imply $\theta = \tan^{-1}(s)$.